# Updating statement using Join/coalesce to show data on gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am working with a query that is being used on a gridview to select data to display:

```
SELECT [Theme].[PK_Theme], [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] 
FROM [Theme] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [ThemeType] 
ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType] 
JOIN [ProductTheme] ON [ProductTheme].[ThemeId]=[Theme].[PK_Theme] 
WHERE ProductTheme.ProductID LIKE @productParam 
AND ProductTheme.ThemeId = Theme.PK_Theme 
AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null') LIKE @assignedParam 
GROUP BY [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type], [Theme].[PK_Theme] 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [ThemeType].[Type] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, [Theme].[Name]
```

The column [THEME].[THEMETYPEID] was previously varchar(50) but has been changed to int.

I am now getting this error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int.
```

One thing that is strange is that I directly query the server the above statement works, (which I change out the parameters for values that is) But its not working in the server control.

The updated column allows for nulls. How do I check for Null for an int in this curcumstance and have the query work as before?

Edit I want the result to be like this if both the parameters are assigned '%':

[image]

Comment: Are you using `DataSet` to retrieve data from db?

Comment: [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType]  what data type is?

Comment: [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType] is int and I'm not using DataSet

Comment: Use NULL instead of 'null'

Comment: Nothing is returned when using NULL

Comment: your issue is with the line COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null') LIKE @assignedParam as you cannot convert the string 'null' to an INT if you want a null it should be NULL without the ''.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null') LIKE @assignedParam
```

Should be (no single quotes):

```
AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], NULL) LIKE @assignedParam
```

Because `'null'` is a normal string while you probably intend to signify a `NULL` value

Or perhaps you should change it to something like :

```
AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 0) LIKE @assignedParam
```

Since ThemeTyeID is an int

**UPDATE:**

Try this:

```
 SELECT  [Theme].[PK_Theme] ,
                [Theme].[Name] ,
                [ThemeType].[Type]
        FROM    [Theme]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [ThemeType] ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType]
                JOIN [ProductTheme] ON [ProductTheme].[ThemeId] = [Theme].[PK_Theme]
        WHERE   ProductTheme.ProductID LIKE @productParam
                AND ProductTheme.ThemeId = Theme.PK_Theme
                AND 1 = CASE WHEN [THEME].[THEMETYPEID] IS NULL THEN 1
                             WHEN [THEME].[THEMETYPEID] LIKE @param THEN 1
                        END
        GROUP BY [Theme].[Name] ,
                [ThemeType].[Type] ,
                [Theme].[PK_Theme]
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN [ThemeType].[Type] IS NULL THEN 0
                      ELSE 1
                 END ,
                [Theme].[Name]
```

But we warned that if this works as you want, it will not be as efficient as writing separate queries for each case. and perhaps union them...

Comment: If I change it to NULL nothing gets returned. If I change it to zero, only NULLs are getting returned. Previously nulls were returned then non nulls next

Comment: @DavidTunnell then your query needs to be written differently in order to return what you want. The point is that your query was failing because you were using `'null'` incorrectly. I will try to provide a query that may do what you want but I can't be sure it will work as you expect since I don't know the requirement.

Comment: I want every [Theme].[Name] along with its associated [Theme].[PK_Theme] in order by where all [ThemeType].[Type] are null first and then non null second, within those two breakdowns I want name to be in alphabetical order. I added an image to give you idea.

Comment: @DavidTunnell I can't see images on my browser but I'll try to post an updated query that hopefully works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code:

```
SELECT [Theme].[PK_Theme], [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] 
FROM [Theme] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [ThemeType] 
ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType] 
JOIN [ProductTheme] ON [ProductTheme].[ThemeId]=[Theme].[PK_Theme] 
WHERE ProductTheme.ProductID LIKE @productParam 
AND ProductTheme.ThemeId = Theme.PK_Theme AND [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] IS NOT NULL 
AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null') LIKE @assignedParam 
GROUP BY [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type], [Theme].[PK_Theme] 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [ThemeType].[Type] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, [Theme].[Name]
```

Comment: Same error, now in sql server management studio also: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int.

Comment: THis runs but returns nothing